# data not showing in listbox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am trying to get a scoreboard to show up in my listbox from a mySQL DB.

However all i get in the list box is 'System.Data.DataRowView'

this is the code:

```
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

string sqlStr = "SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' ', Score) as NameAndScore " + "FROM highscore ORDER BY Score DESC";

MySqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConn);

DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
dAdapter.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill before binding.

```
 dAdapter.Fill(dTable);
 lstNames.DataSource = dTable;
 lstNames.DisplayMember = "NameAndScore";
```

Comment: This is how i had it previously but still get the same error.

Comment: @CainNeal Check, does datatable populated after fill in debug mode.

Comment: Very important detail: You must set `DisplayMember` *after* `DataSource`.